# BootstrapTour Navigation prblm between different Pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am using bootstrap Tour.. It works well on Single page and Goes efficiently from one page(first.html) to another (second.html) with the help of "Next" button... Problem is that when i press previous button (on second.html) page it  never goes to first.html page.. Any Help to solve the Problem

My Code is Below

newly.html(FirstPage)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="build/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="build/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="build/js/Script.js"></script>


    <style>
        .new {
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 500px;
            padding: 50px;
            background: #EBEBEB;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test" class="new">
        <h1>Header Part</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="test1" class="new">
        <h1>Footer Part</h1>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

mine.html(SecondPage)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="build/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="build/js/bootstrap-tour-standalone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="build/js/Script.js"></script>
    <title>mine</title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
        .man {
            float: left;
            background: red;
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="dumy" class="man">
        <h1>This is My Self Made Div</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(function () {
    var tour = new Tour({
        steps: [
        {
            element: "#test",
            title: "Title of my step",
            content: "This is Header"
        },
        {

            element: "#test1",
            title: "Title of my step",
            content: "This is footer"
        },
        {
            path: "/mine.html",
            element: "#dumy",
            title: "Title of my step",
            content: "I made this step own",
           // backdrop: true

        }
        ]
    });
    // Initialize the tour
    tour.init();

    // Start the tour
    tour.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick logic of my mind and spent a day over this finally found answer myself... and only one line kept me stuck whole day :| :\

edit second step or add path to second step

Updated Script.js

```
$(function () {
    var tour = new Tour({
        steps: [
        {
            element: "#test",
            title: "Title of my step",
            content: "This is Header"
        },
        {   
            //add path to the second step
            path: "/newly.html",
            element: "#test1",
            title: "Title of my step",
            content: "This is footer"
        },
        {
            path: "/mine.html",
            element: "#dumy",
            title: "Title of my step",
            content: "I made this step own",
           // backdrop: true

        }
        ]
    });
    // Initialize the tour
    tour.init();

    // Start the tour
    tour.start();
});
```